# Automator on a SMB server

Tags: automator

Trying to have Automator perform tasks on a smb:// mounted volume. Currently it can make a "New Folder" but is unable to make use of "Find Finder Items" as this yields no results. I can manually create and delete files via Finder, so permissions should't be an issue. [image]

Comment: What results have been returned by the first action (click on "Results" to see them)?

Comment: It says "No results produced." I tried swapping the "Move Finder Items" to "New Text Document" but it just comes up empty. It works when running the same script locally.

Comment: Spotlight doesn't index SMB shares. Apparently you can force it, but it needs 're-forcing' at every mount. - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4689881