# Automator questions - Copying files to new location

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, video, folders

So I have some questions about the Automator.

I'm doing a fairly simple task with it and that's why it boggles my mind that it doesn't work. Always brings me the same info

- "The action "Filter Finder Items" was not supplied with the required data"

So what I'm doing is.

1. I receive video files from a client.
2. Download it to SERVER-1.
3. If the video is pretty big, I compress it to make it smaller and choose a folder on SERVER-2.
4. After the conversion has happened, I need to move the newly converted file to SERVER-3

I want Automator to understand that as soon as the file has been converted and placed on the desired folder on SERVER 2, to copy the file and place it on the corresponding folder on SERVER 3.

[image]

This is the action that I've made. The first one "Find Finder Items" seems pointless to me cause I'm already looking at that same folder with "Folder Action" but I tried it regardless if that could give the other two actions more data to perform their tasks correctly.

Also tried to use the "any content - Contains ***" for multiple things but nothing seems to be working.

Note, I have no background in coding or anything like that so it's a bit out of my wheelhouse to start writing codes but I guess that's the way to go since the actions from the action list are not doing what I need.

Could someone chime in and help me figure this out, receiving an insane amount of data and doing it all my hand is doing my head in.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me out here!

Comment: afaik, "Find Finder Items" relies on Spotlight having indexed the location. SMB shares do not index unless you force them & they need re-forcing at every mount. [This cropped up in another question recently, but I'm having trouble tracking it down]

Comment: Found it - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437309/automator-on-a-smb-server Comment referencing https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4689881

Comment: Ahh thank you for your answer.
I guess then it wouldn't really work as an automated task since it'll neet to be re-forced at every mount?